# How do I hide empyy lines in a Python file in Vim?

Tags: vim, python, syntax-highlighting

I have some empty lines showing as dark purple lines in my color theme in vim(Gvim). I would like to hide them for real. I  use "set list" but that just replaces with some other characters. I just want to hide those lines, rather I want them to look like the rest of theme in the file, I find them distracting.

See the image for what is going on please.

I realize they are helpful but to me they are distracting. I might need to check out spaces here in the file and there but that is not something I want to see at all times.

I do not want to run some predefined commands to clear the white spaces if possible. I just want to do this on the syntax/session side.

[image: spaces]

Comment: The dark boxes look like highlighting of trailing whitespace.

Comment: Yes they do like I  mentioned in my post, and that is what I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from. If you don't find a syntax group, check whether `:call clearmatches()` removes the highlighting.